# Call stack window does not display local values

Tags: keil, nrf51

I'm running a debug session.

I set a break point inside of function `services_init` on line 201.

I ran the `run up to break point` command

[image]

The processor pauses on line 201 as expected. However, the stack window only displays variables local to the `main` function.

Why don't I see the variables local to `services_init`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A developer from Nordic solved my problem

> Hi,
>
> Try going into project settings -> C/C++ tab, and set optimization
>   level to -O0. Then re-compile and flash the firmware again. When
>   enabling higher optimization, the compiler looks for patterns in your
>   all of your code, squishes similar sections together, and the outcome
>   is not as streamlined as your source code. This is the reason why
>   debugging with high optimization may give inconsistent "jumps" in
>   code, and the call stack may not show all variables correctly.
>
> Cheers, Håkon